# How to automatically add edit link on frontpage post of any wordpress theme?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, plugin-recommendation

Hi I searched google for a plugin to do so, I can't find any. Can you recommend me one if not can I create it myself though I'm beginner in wordpress dev ? If yes can you give me some clues.

Thanks.

Update: I'm not interested in having edit link in admin bar; I bought a plugin which instructs me something I don't want to do by hand on dozens of themes :

[image]

Please give me an answer, I'm desperate :)

Comment: You have a edit link in the admin bar, if the user have this admin bar active in the user settings and is logged in. Maybe this is enough.

Comment: @bueltge you're right sorry I wasn't precise enough so I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As lot of themes use `the_content()` to display the post content. you can use `the_content` filter hook to add the edit link before/after the content.

Since you want this work outside themes, you have to put the following code in a file, and store it in your plugins folder then activate it as a plugin.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Add Edit Link in Frontend
 * Description: Append post edit link to content
 * Version: 1.0.0
 */

function wpael_content_edit_link( $content ) {

    $content .= '<br /><div style="font-size: 14px"><a href="'.  get_edit_post_link( get_the_ID() ) . '">Edit</a></div>';
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpael_content_edit_link', 10 );
```